# Does it make sense to learn objective c first before jumping into xcode and cocoa touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am now migrating into iOS development using it's native tools since i was developing before using adobe air. I'm just really confuse where to start on iOS development. I followed some of the tutorials from apple using "STORY BOARDS" but I'm not satisfied on its method. I know there's a way to make an app programatically. Unfortunately, knowing where to start between objective-c, cocoa touch and x-code really confuse me since I'm not familiar on those things. Which one of the three should I start with

Comment: I think you need to start with all three at once.

Comment: As a beginner, I would perhaps go straight to Swift (instead of Objective C) these days ...

Comment: @trojanfoe- Which of three first?

Comment: @Drux - Yes, Swift is the next big thing for iOS but on my opinion, It might be not mature compared to the tried and tested objective c. Also most the biggest production house of iOS uses objective-c. I think they will not invest that easily to convert their objective c program into swift.

Comment: @user3814619 The latest version of Xcode will assume that your new projects will use Swift instead of Objective-C unless you tell it otherwise. Apple cannot afford to let that one fail. Also Objective-C is far behind the current state-of-the-art in programming languages IMHO. But I can see your point of view and also have not (fully) made the transition yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you'll have to learn all 3 at the same time. All 3 work together. Objective-C is the language that iOS apps are programmed in (yes, you can combine it with other languages like C++) - and Swift, like a couple commenters mentioned, is something that is probably worth learning now since Apple is trying to migrate to that. (Note that Swift works hand in hand with Objective-C.)

Xcode is the IDE that iOS developers use to create iOS apps. Xcode allows you to compile Objective-C code (along with other C based languages), and allows you to create storyboards, as you mentioned. (Storyboards are not supposed to be used on their own, they work with view controllers and such, and are supposed to be manipulated by your code.)

Objective-C uses the Cocoa Touch library, which is the library that Apple created to be used with the iOS platform. Cocoa (not Cocoa Touch) is very similar, and is used for Mac apps.